# Map resized image coordinates back to the original

Tags: javascript, php, image, resize

So here is an interesting one (or at least I think it is).

Turns out that I have two copies of the same image, the original and one resized to fit the window.

The user then creates a polygon over the resized version of the image and with some javascript I send the coordinates to a php script which then merges the polygon into the original image.

The problem is, the resized coordinates are not the same for the original image, still there is a relation between them.

Here is the code of how I resize the image in js:

```
if(h > 610 || w > 815){
                    while(h > 610 || w > 815){
                        h = Math.ceil(h*0.80);
                        w = Math.ceil(w*0.80);
                    }
                }
```

This code allows me to keep the image inside the workspace (which is 610 x 815) and at the same time keeping some aspect ratio.

Then in php I attempt to revert the resize within each coordinate, but here is where Im stuck:

```
$values = array();

            $num_points = count($polyCoords);


            foreach($polyCoords as $coord){
                array_push($values, intval($coord['x']) /* +- RELOCATE FACTOR? */ );
                array_push($values, intval($coord['y']) /* +- RELOCATE FACTOR? */ );
            }
```

Can someone give me a hand of how to calculate this "relocate factor" for each point?
I have the original size and the resized... size.

Any ideas will be must apreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using percentages? I'm not entirely sure if it will be accurate enough though. Something like:

```
$newcoord['x'] = ($coord['x']/$originalWidth) * $newWidth;
$newcoord['y'] = ($coord['y']/$originalHeight) * $newHeight;
```